# How to fix a problem with the featured image in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, image

Currently, I'm using the classic WordPress editor, but when I want to add or update the featured image I get something like a transparent image, no URL and no description, besides that it doesn't let me update or set a new image.

Do you know any solution for this?

[image]

Comment: Open browser console and try uploading image to check for errors. You can get clue from there, I think could be folder permission issue.

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be due to folder permission.

1. change upload folder permission 777
2. change your theme and active WordPress default theme.
3. Disable plugins one by one